# On Azure DevOps, how can a user have access to every projects of an organization?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We would like to give users access to every projects in our organization, as soon as a new project is created.
From what I've tried, I can only manually add users to projects, or use a group rule to add projects permissions to the users.

Is it possible to have users access every projects of the organization, without manual intervention from the Administrators ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any mechanism which allows you to automatically assign a group to a new project (like a template) - at least there is no functionality within the organization *Policies* settings.

I think manually assign a certain group for every new project is the way to go here. However, if every user should have a high permission level, you could have a look at **Collection-level / Organization-level groups**.

See: [Security groups, service accounts, and permissions in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)